# Submit input content without being edited

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I had a piece of software and it allows users to partly edit their existing information. But it occurs that only the edited part is submitted correctly while the unedited ones become empty.
I figure the issue is that I changed the value by assigning value using attribute `onChange`, which is executed if I don't change anything in the input. So is there another event attribute, say, `onExist`, so that I could assign the value to the variable as long as it shows up in the input?

```
const [company, setCompany] = useState('');
const [position, setPosition] = useState('');
const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
const [add, setAdd] = useState(false);

const handleSubmit = useCallback(async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let exp = {
            CompanyName: company,
            Position: position,
            description: description,
            start_date: startDate,
            end_date: endDate,
            JobType: type
        };

        ////////////////
        // do something and store exp to database
        ////////////////

        setAdd(false);
        setEdit(false);  
    });

return (
<div>
      <input className="input-box__reference" placeholder="Company Name" name="CompName" defaultValue={experienceToEdit.CompanyName} onChange={e => setCompany(e.target.value)} required></input>
      <input className="input-box__reference" placeholder="Position" name="Position" defaultValue={experienceToEdit.Position} onChange={e => setPosition(e.target.value)} required></input>
</div>
<button class="sign-btn" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
)
```

Apart from that, is it possible to disable the button if any one of the input fields is cleared empty?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you always want to have your value updated to the input's value, you have to assign it to your state, and if you want the **defaultValue** behaviour, add your "defaultValue" as a starting value in your `useState` function call.

```
// Here you define a defaultValue for "company"
const [company, setCompany] = useState(experienceToEdit.CompanyName);
```

Then change the **defaultValue** prop to **value** in your jsx:

```
<input
    className="input-box__reference"
    placeholder="Company Name" name="CompName"
    value={company}
    onChange={e => setCompany(e.target.value)}
    required
/>
```

**There's another consideration you should have**, **useCallback** is used to define memoization to a function, it's second argument is an array of dependencies **when those dependencies change, the callback would change**, so, if you always want the latest values, **don't use useCallback or add the variables you need to the array of dependencies**

Comment: Well it looks like a good way, but it will conflict with my operation if a user creating an item. So setting `experienceToEdit.CompanyName` using `useState` at the beginning looks not so available to me.

Comment: Maybe [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) would help you